# How to pass data from parent view to child view's viewModel - SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am making an app where I am showing posts in Feedview. FeedView has a childView named FeedCellView. I am sending each post to corresponding FeedCellView. In FeedCellView it has `init()` function where I am initialising the ViewModel.

The problem is in SwiftUI, view's `init()` calls from 1 to infinity. Thus it is not certain that my view's `init()` will be called or not. As for this when I come back to my FeedView from a different view my posts are not updating, since `init()` is called only once for me.

So I should not pass data from view's init to view model as it is uncertain. What is the best practice to pass data from parent view to Child's view Model?

FeedView:

```
struct FeedView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var feedViewModel = FeedViewModel()
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(){
            LazyVStack(spacing:32){
                ForEach(feedViewModel.posts){post in
                    FeedCellView(viewModel: FeedCellViewModel(post: post))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

FeedCellView:

```
struct FeedCellView: View {
    @ObservedObject var feedCellViewModel:FeedCellViewModel
    
    init(viewModel:FeedCellViewModel){ //This is not being called more than once.
        self.feedCellViewModel = viewModel
        print("feed Cell View Init")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment:.leading){
            
            if let user = feedCellViewModel.post.user{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: ProfileView(user: user),
                    label: {
                        HStack{
                            if let imageUrl = feedCellViewModel.post.ownerImageUrl{
                                KFImage(URL(string: imageUrl))
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFill()
.............................
.............................
```

FeedCellViewModel:

```
class FeedCellViewModel:ObservableObject{
    @Published var post:PostModel
    
    init(post:PostModel){ 
        self.post = post
        fetchUser()
        checkLike()
    }
    
    func fetchUser(){
        print("Feed cell ViewModel fetchUser called")
        Firestore.firestore().collection("users").document(post.ownerId).getDocument { (snap, error) in
            if let error = error{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.post.user = try? snap?.data(as: UserModel.self)
                guard let userImageUrl = self.post.user?.profileImageUrl else{return}
                self.post.ownerImageUrl = userImageUrl
                print("OwnerImageUrl \(self.post.ownerUsername): \(self.post.ownerImageUrl ?? "No Image Url")")
            }
            
        }
    }
.....................
.....................
```

What is the best practice to pass data from parent view to child view's viewModel?

Comment: Change your view model properties from `@ObservedObject` to `@StateObject`

Comment: I would suggest having posts in FeedViewModel be and array of FeedCellViewModels. That way you could completely bypass the init part of FeedCellViewModel (delete it), and in my opinion have cleaner MVVM, where model objects do not make it to the view layer. You would have something like this:
ForEach(feedViewModel.posts){feedCellViewModel in
                    FeedCellView(feedCellViewModel: feedCellViewModel)
                }

Comment: Thank you. I have deleted init and created array of feedCellViewModels in feedViewModel. And Fetching fresh data in onAppear() instead of init() and it is working. Can You please answer the question so that I can accept it?